# Parse Class Relations query

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com Tool.

I have a Post class where it contains list of posts. 
Users can *like* the post which happens by storing the action in a Like class with pointer to the post id in the Post class and pointer to the user id in the User class.

The problem I am trying to solve is the following:
When I get the list of posts, I want to know which of them the user liked and which he didn't.

What's the best solution knowing that this list can be long list.

Comment: You should be able to get all the values you require by construction PFQueries which you perform on the "Like" class which you have created.

Comment: i'm facing a similar situation, can anyone provide some code? @ahar083

Answer (score 0):

I would do two queries.

1. Get the Posts you want.
2. Get the ids of the Posts from the Likes table, where the User pointer is pointing to your current user.

Then compare the lists against each other.

If you only want Posts that the user has liked and not others you could do one query to the Likes table and get the Post object from that.

Provide a few more details if you want some code. Like what you are developing for (ios, android, web).

Comment: Thanks, you solution is valid but I wanted to do that with one query only to be fast.
I am developing on Android but using Parse.com solution for the backend